# Adding text files content into a list of lists

Tags: python

I want to "read" the content of many txt files I have in a dir, to a list.
The thing is that I want every object in the list to be a list too.

I'd like to be able to access each "file" (or content of a file) by the index - in order to later train it with an NLP model. Also, that's why I used the `line.strip()` because I need each content to be stripped into "lines".

Here is the code I tried, however, I get the Error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\User1\Article\BBC\bbc\entertainment')
ent_txts = glob.glob('*.txt')

ent_docs = []
d=0

for i in ent_txts:
    
    with open(i, 'r') as f:
        
         for line in f:
                ent_docs[d].append(line.strip())
    d+=1
```

I think the problem is with the fact that I'm trying to address a list index that hasn't been created.
I'm sure there's must be a simple way to do it, though I can't find it.

I'd be glad for any help!

Comment: Show a proper [MCVE]: 3 files with representative names and minimal content (3 lines each). Show what your code does in that case, explain what you actually want, and analyzes the discrepancy. See [ask]

Comment: change to, ```ent_docs = [None] * len(ent_txts)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you don't have any inner list to insert to. I would fix it like so:

```
for i in ent_txts:
    with open(i, 'r') as f:
        file_lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
    ent_docs.append(file_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\User1\Article\BBC\bbc\entertainment')
ent_txts = glob.glob('*.txt')

ent_docs = defaultdict(list)
d=0

for i in ent_txts:
    
    with open(i, 'r') as f:
        
         for line in f:
                ent_docs[d].append(line.strip())
    d+=1
```